# Can't Factory Reset HTC Desire C

Tags: rooting, factory-reset, bootloader, htc-desire-c

I tried unlocking the bootloader (which I apparently succeeded at.)  I then tried rooting it, which I failed at.  I just want to reset the phone back to factory settings but when I try to do a factory reset it will reboot into the (and I don't know if this is the right name for it or not) bootloader screen, where it says my phone is relocked and gives me the options "bootloader", "reboot", "reboot bootloader" and "power down"

What do I do?  If I reboot the phone will restart but nothing has been erased.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just flash it with a stock ROM, also you should always backup any device before you screw with the operating system (this goes for computers and phones!)

Make sure that the ROM you flash your phone with matches the phone EXACTLY. If you get a ROM that is for your phone, but for a different carrier, it will brick your phone and you will be out of luck.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the bootloader is really unlocked, you should install a custom rom.

Personally, I like the explos!on rom, which can be found here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2000636

Unfortunately, HTC has not released a RUU for this phone, so it will be impossible to flash the original ROM.